# On which node first transaction will be executed in Always-on setup?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a scenario where SQL Server 2012 - Always-on feature configured.The primary and secondary are synchronous for failover purposes. I understand that we will have node 1 (PRIMARY) and node 2 . Also I know during fail over node 2 becomes PRIMARY.

My question is, (synchronous commit setup)

1. When application send INSERT or any SQL transactions, which node first the execution happens? Is it on PRIMARY ?
2. When node 1 fails then node 2 becomes PRIMARY, but who will make node 1 up?  do I need to setup alerts? if node 1 dies then how HA and DR works?
3. What is difference between active-passive or active-active?

Where I can find detailed information on always-on architecture? I have read many article but none explains the internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) From [Overview of AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx)

> The primary replica sends **transaction log records of each primary database** to every secondary database. Every secondary replica **caches the transaction log** records (hardens the log) **and then applies** them to its corresponding secondary database.

So, primary first, then secondary.

2) Are you asking how node 1 is brought back on line? That's what your operations people and DBAs are paid their huge salaries to do.

Alerts would be a good idea. Maybe even a very good idea.

If node 1 dies AlwaysOn will re-direct connects to node 2, transparently to the application. In-flight work may receive an error. New connections will be routed to node 2. This *is* the HA and DR in action. When node 1 comes back you can continue running on node 2 as primary and have node 1 as secondary, or organise a managed failback at a time of your choice. If node 2 dies while node 1 is still down, then you have a problem.

3) Active-passive has the secondary as "warm": it is ready to become the primary when required but cannot do any application work until then. Active-active has a "hot" secondary: it can process read-only transaction from the application, and be used for backups and such like. IIRC one license is needed for active-passive and two for active-active.

Comment: perfect explanation. Thanks.  "If node 2 dies while node 1 is still down, then you have a problem." -  can we automate it through script to solve this problem or Is it DBA's job?

Comment: If depends on why node 1 died. If it was a glitch in the OS then an automated reboot would be worth a try. If that data centre is on fire, then, no, I don't think a script would help.

Comment: Michael, can you help here too? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131953/how-to-enable-disable-sql-agent-jobs-during-fail-over-alwayson